# Javascript function sending request twice to struts action class

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a JS function which is sending request twice to action class. I am not sure where should I modify it to resolve the issue.

Below is the JS function.The problem is in ELSE part of it where I am checking runNoEmail==1 && runEmail==0
I am providing full JS function for better understanding

```
function runReportCheck(obj){
     obj = window.event.srcElement;  
     if(runEmail==1 && runNoEmail==0) 
        {
         openPopupWindow('popupType:Working');          
         runEmail=0;
             var opt = {
                     method: 'post',
                     parameters: $('formLicStrands').serialize(true),
                     onSuccess: function(t) {                 
                     destroyPopupWindow();                                                 
                             if(t.responseText=="-2"){  
                                openPopupWindow('title:Error; message: Conflict report is already being run.Please try again later.; popupType: Error; button1Value: OK;  topRightClose: false',obj);                                                   
                                 return;          
                             }else                               
                               if(t.responseText=="-3"){
                                openPopupWindow('title:Warning; message: The conflict report will run and save in the background.An email will be sent to you upon completion.; popupType: Warning; button1Value: OK;  topRightClose: false',obj);                                
                                return;
                                    }  
                               else
                               {  openPopupWindow('title:Run And Email Issue Report; URL:<c:url value="/secure/deal/conflict/newReport.dooo?"/>;formToSubmit:formLicStrands;topRightClose: false;onTitleBarCloseFunction:onConflictReportClose(<c:out value="${DEAL_BRIEF.ventanaId}"/>)',obj);  
                                }
                               return;                                            
                     },
                     onFailure: function(t) {
                         alert('Error ' + t.status + ' -- ' + t.responseText);
                     }
                 }          
                 new Ajax.Request("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/secure/deal/conflict/newReport.dooo?isRunEmailClicked=true",opt);
                 return false;
        } 
        else if(runNoEmail==1 && runEmail==0) 
        {       
         openPopupWindow('popupType:Working');          
         runNoEmail=0;
             var opt = {
                     method: 'post',
                     parameters: $('formLicStrands').serialize(true),
                     onSuccess: function(t) {                 
                     destroyPopupWindow();                                                 
                             if(t.responseText=="-11"){ 
                                openPopupWindow('title:Error; message: Conflict report is already being run.Please try again later.; popupType: Error; button1Value: OK;  topRightClose: false',obj);                                                   
                                 return;          
                             } 
                               else
                               {
                                   openPopupWindow('title:Run Issue Report; URL:<c:url value="/secure/deal/conflict/newReport.dooo?"/>;formToSubmit:formLicStrands;topRightClose: false;onTitleBarCloseFunction:onConflictReportClose(<c:out value="${DEAL_BRIEF.ventanaId}"/>)',obj);  
                                }
                               return;                                            
                     },
                     onFailure: function(t) {
                         alert('Error ' + t.status + ' -- ' + t.responseText);
                     }
                 }          
                 new Ajax.Request("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/secure/deal/conflict/newReport.dooo",opt);
                 return false;
        }else {         
            openPopupWindow('title:Run Issue Report; URL:<c:url value="/secure/deal/conflict/newReport.dooo?"/>;formToSubmit:formLicStrands;topRightClose: false;onTitleBarCloseFunction:onConflictReportClose(<c:out value="${DEAL_BRIEF.ventanaId}"/>)',obj);
            }
    return;}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: My action class is calling twice from ELSE part. I want to prevent it.It should call only once.

Comment: It looks like you have the same condition of `if (runNoEmail==1 && runEmail==0)` and `else if(runNoEmail==1 && runEmail==0)`. They both appear to be firing

Comment: No they are different if(runEmail==1 && runNoEmail==0) and else if else if(runNoEmail==1 && runEmail==0)